# For cleaning HVAC with Lysol, should the AC be on or off?

Tags: honda, ac, hvac, smell, crv

Many people recommend spraying Lysol Disinfectant Spray or similar products into the HVAC intake to kill mold and bad odors inside HVAC.

Should the AC be on or off for this procedure?

As far as I can tell, the evaporator coil is the most likely location of mold growth. If the AC is on, the coil will be cool, and stuff will condense on it. So it makes sense to run the AC for a while before you spray Lysol into the HVAC intake.

However, I haven't seen this bit being mentioned.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to turn the ac on have the fan on full speed, turn off the recirculation, spray the lysol. roll the windows down blah blah.....

Watch this video this has the complete procedure and the answer I just copied it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrVc_FXrbHY